# Can someone please explain why one of these webkit animation functions works and the other doesn't. I know its the class vs ID but why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, webkit-animation

This is just test code so don't think about it too much. But anyways I cant understand why animation play states will work and change fine when a class is used but not when I use an ID.

Is there other rules when using ID's or can you not use ID's?

Any information would be very helpful.

WORKING VERSION USING CLASSES

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 2s infinite;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 2s infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 250px;}
}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 250px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="playTest()">Play</button>
<button onclick="playTest2()">Pause</button>

<script>

function playTest(){
    document.getElementById("notMyDIV").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running"; // Code for Chrome, Safari, and Opera
    document.getElementById("notMyDIV").style.animationPlayState = "running";
}

function playTest2(){
    document.getElementById("notMyDIV").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused"; // Code for Chrome, Safari, and Opera
    document.getElementById("notMyDIV").style.animationPlayState = "paused";
}


</script>
<div id="notMyDIV">
  <div id="myDIV"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

NON-WORKING ID VERSION

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.myDiv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: mymove 2s infinite;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: mymove 2s infinite;
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 250px;}
}

@keyframes mymove {
    from {left: 0px;}
    to {left: 250px;}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="playTest()">Play</button>
<button onclick="playTest2()">Pause</button>

<script>

function playTest(){
    document.getElementById("notMyDIV").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running"; // Code for Chrome, Safari, and Opera
    document.getElementById("notMyDIV").style.animationPlayState = "running";
}

function playTest2(){
    document.getElementById("notMyDIV").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused"; // Code for Chrome, Safari, and Opera
    document.getElementById("notMyDIV").style.animationPlayState = "paused";
}


</script>
<div id="notMyDIV">
  <div class="myDiv" id="myDIV"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not due to the div having a class or not. The reason the second example fails is that the CSS selector (`.myDiv`) is not selecting the `div#notMyDiv`, but is selecting the child `div.myDiv`, to which the animation play state is not being applied to.

In the first div, the selector is selecting all divs (`div`), which is why it works.

Here is the second snippet, except the javascript applies the play state to the child div, selected by the CSS selector.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    .myDiv {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: red;
      position: relative;
      -webkit-animation: mymove 2s infinite;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
      animation: mymove 2s infinite;
      animation-play-state: paused;
    }

    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    @-webkit-keyframes mymove {
      from {left: 0px;}
      to {left: 250px;}
    }

    @keyframes mymove {
      from {left: 0px;}
      to {left: 250px;}
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="playTest()">Play</button>
    <button onclick="playTest2()">Pause</button>
    <script>
    function playTest(){
      document.getElementById("myDIV").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running"; // Code for Chrome, Safari, and Opera
      document.getElementById("myDIV").style.animationPlayState = "running";
    }

    function playTest2(){
      document.getElementById("myDIV").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "paused"; // Code for Chrome, Safari, and Opera
      document.getElementById("myDIV").style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    }
    </script>
    <div id="notMyDIV">
      <div class="myDiv" id="myDIV"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow thats super obvious. Im not sure why I put the parent. Definitely spent to much time looking at screens today. Thanks